# How can we define the Inner Product of multi-variable functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can we define the Inner Product of multi-variable functions?

For example, what is the value of the inner product of $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$?

$$\langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle = ?? $$

Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is used for the inner product in $L^2$.

Comment: $\langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)} = \sum_i \int_\Omega \partial_i f\, \partial_i g\, dx$.

Comment: @martini As I expected! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ashuley Use '\langle \rangle' which gives $\langle \rangle$ instead of $<>$.

Comment: @martini How about $\langle f, g \rangle \text{where} f(x,y) \text{and } g(x,y)$? Thanks